# Smooth mouse-out animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a diamond shaped div that spins 360 degrees around its own axis on hover by using CSS animation.

I can't work it out how to ensure **smooth going back to the original state** when not hovering anymore?

So far it "jumps" when the diamond is in the middle of its turn. I would like it to be smooth. Is it possible to do it with CSS animations? If not, maybe with JS?

```css
.dn-diamond {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dn-diamond:hover {
  animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotateY(0deg) rotate(-45deg); }
  to   { transform: rotateY(360deg) rotate(-45deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="dn-diamond">
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1wqtd2k/)

I was trying to use the transition but could not keep the original transformed shape of it (it went back to being a square, not a diamond).

Comment: Seems to transition smoothly for me in Chrome. Noticed you haven't included all prefixes for `@keyframes`

Comment: I have checked it in Chrome too and it still "jumps" as I move my cursor away from it, e.g. a second or less after you hover over it. :-( You are right about the prefixes though - thanks! I need to add them

Comment: It might be worthwhile looking into GSAP if you're creating complex animations: http://greensock.com/gsap

Comment: Just as a hint, it works for me when the mouse cursor is strictly on the center of the "diamond" but  when I get a bit to the left/right it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SamuelMS, I would've never thought about using something like this before as I assumed spinning a CSS shape and nice smooth state on "going back to its original state" is a basic thing

Comment: Thanks @user3272243 for the info, I haven't noticed it myself unless I keep the cursor on the shape for longer than around 1.5 seconds

Comment: @Niralana I'm pretty sure that happens because when you are on the center with the cursor the cursor is always "seeing" the div, but when it moves away from "its vision" then the effect stops. What you could do is put it into another div that is the ones that triggers the other one to move, this way that other static div will be always seen by the cursor. Quite a cheap solution but if it works... it works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) for this. They will allow you to keep the transition smooth when the mouse moves out of the element.

Example :

```css
.dn-diamond {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transition: transform 3s linear;
  margin: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dn-diamond:hover {
  transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="dn-diamond">
```

---

You can also **control the speed of the transition** when the cursor moves out of the element by setting the transition property on normal and hover state.

Example :

```css
.dn-diamond {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
  margin: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dn-diamond:hover {
  transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transition: transform 3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="dn-diamond">
```

*Note that in the above demos the vendor prefixes aren't included. check [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) to know which vendor prefixes you need according to the browsers you want to support.*

Comment: Is it just me or does the "wind-down" when you stop hovering seem to transition more slowly?

Comment: @SamuelMS the transition on mouse out will always have the same duration independent on how far the on hover animation went so if you hover in and out quickly, the second animation will look slower. If you let the first animation go all the way, the mouse out animation will have the same speed. For control over both animations, see the second example.

Comment: Thanks very much @web-tiki! I am new to transforms, animations and transitions, hence the question: is there any way to make the "diamond" spin more than once?

Comment: @Niralana you can add a higher value to `rotateY()` on the hover state. If you want it to spin twice, you need to add `360deg * 2 = 720deg`

Comment: Okay, that would solve it @web-tiki. Besides, would I have to use some JS to make the going back state as only one turn, independent on how many spins the shape made? Just being curious.

Comment: @Niralana yes, that would require JS as CSS can't "count" the number of spins

Answer (score 3):

Give `transitions` for `transform`:

```
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease-in;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s ease-in;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 3s ease-in;
          transition: transform 3s ease-in;
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.dn-diamond {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
  margin: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dn-diamond:hover {
  transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 3s ease-in;
  transition: transform 3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="dn-diamond">
```